# Bound on $p$-norm of power of function.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose I have a function $u\in L^p(\Omega)$, with $1\leq p <\infty$. Clearly, for $r\geq 1$,

$$
\|u^r\|_p = \|u\|_{rp}^r.
$$

Now, for $r>1$, I would like to be able to write $\|u^r\|_p\leq C \|u\|_s$, for some $s\geq 1$, $C>0$ (independent on $u$). My intuition says that this is not possible, but I was wondering if there were any additional requirement on $u$, and/or $p$ and/or $r$ that would make it possible. We can assume $\Omega$ bounded and smooth, and, if it helps, $u\in H^1(\Omega)$.

---

Edit: to give a concrete example, I'd like to find (if any) conditions on $u$ and $s$ that make the following valid:

$$
\|u\|_8^2 = \|u^2\|_4\leq C(s)\|u\|_s.
$$

Note: if $|u|<1$ pointwise, then this is clearly true, since $|u|^p<|u|$. However, I do not have such information. But, if it helps, I have the following inequality

$$
\|u\|_4^4 \leq A \|u\|_8^2.
$$

What if I also have $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$? Would that help?

Comment: You have to make some restrictions on the functions $u$, like an $\mathbb L^p$ norm bounded by $1$. Otherwise, the wanted inequality may fail when $u$ is replaced by (say) $2u$.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure I see why. However, sure, we can focus on the case where $\|u\|_p<1$. That's actually the scenario I have.